Can I operate DVD Drive Tray Mechanism without PC?
I want to make a motorized drawer using a broken DVD drive. I'd like to use the tray mechanism as a whole if possible. I can drive the motor by directly applying power to it, but I don't want to add a limit switch or any other mechanism to check if it's fully opened or closed. Is it possible to control it with a microcontroller and ensure it stops when fully open or fully closed? Maybe someone has done this before. Thanks for all the info! Here is a picture of the PCB:

I'm using these connections to drive motor.


But the tray assembly already contains the limit switch, so you don't specially need to add it any more. There's two switches, one says when the sled is fully open and motor should stop, the other says when the sled is fully closed so motor should stop.

The limit switches are not working when I apply current directly to the motor, and unfortunately, I don't know which pins to use to make them work. I think I need to apply some signal or voltage through the connections on the white ribbon cable.

If the tray is lightly loaded and the mechanism's gear train is robust, you might try sensing motor current. When the tray reaches either limit, the motor stalls, and its current rises greatly. You may have to delay current sense for a moment when you start the motor, to get past the start-up current spike.

@sword1st The limit switch pins are there to also connect directly like the motor. Or you can use the white ribbon cable. Your photo shows where all connections go, motor, led, pushbutton, and the limit switches.

Unfortunately, I can't read the PCB traces as you do. I edited the last photo to show where I apply the voltage. Can you describe which pins and signals I should apply on the ribbon cable or any other pins? There are 8 pins from top to bottom; let's say pin 1 is at the top as a reference :) @Justme

@sword1st then connect to the component pins directly like you did for the motor.

From top to bottom:
Pin 1 - LED1/2 anode (+)
Pin 2 - Motor B/TP2
Pin 3 - Can't see, likely limit switch TRAY_OUT
Pin 4 - Motor A/TP1
Pin 5 - Can't see, likey limit switch TRAY_IN
Pin 6 - Eject button SW1
Pin 7 - Ground/Common terminal for evrything else than the motor
Most of that already reads on the PCB.

Thank you so much! I applied voltage to pin 2 and pin 4, and it worked. Now I have to use the limit switch signals, I guess. I will try to figure it out by myself, but if you have any extra info to give me, I would be appreciated a lot! :) My plan is to connect pin 3 and pin 5 to an ESP32 and check their status (low or high). If it goes well, I can use some H-bridge to reverse the polarity depending on the position. The components for reversing polarity is probably on the other PCB, which this white ribbon connects. Thanks again!

Maybe this will be useful for others later. I set the pin mode as pull-up, and here are the readings:
When the tray is fully closed, I read pin 3 and pin 5 as low.
When the tray is in the middle, I read pin 3 as high and pin 5 as low.
When the tray is fully opened, I read pin 3 and pin 5 as high.
Thanks again for your help!
